# React context provider does not show defaults

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to keep things organized with my project. So I created a `config` folder in which I placed a `context` folder. Inside the `context` folder I want to handle all things context.

So I have `index.ts` which is as follows:

```
import { ThemeContextProvider } from './context';
export default ThemeContextProvider;
```

And a `context.tsx` file with the following:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const ThemeContext = createContext({});
export const ThemeContextProvider = ThemeContext.Provider;
```

In my `app.tsx` I have

```
import React from 'react';
import ThemeContextProvider from './config/context';
import theme from './theme';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeContextProvider value={theme}>
      ...
    </ThemeContextProvider>
  );
}
```

The above works. But I want to move the theme into `context.tsx` and load it there as default so I keep my `App.tsx` as clean as possible

So in `context.tsx` I change to:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
import theme from '../../theme';

export const ThemeContext = createContext(theme);
export const ThemeContextProvider = ThemeContext.Provider;
```

And in `App.tsx` I change `<ThemeContextProvider value={theme}>` to `<ThemeContextProvider>`

React immediately complains about `<ThemeContextProvider>` and wants the `value` prop. When I pass `value={}` and try to get default values from the context, they are no longer there.

Any ideas what's going on and advise about how to handle it, and also advise about best practices? Perhaps I'm going at it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another component that wraps the content and passes the theme to the context provider

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
import theme from '../../theme';

export const ThemeContext = createContext({});
export const ThemeContextProvider = ThemeContext.Provider;
export const YourContextProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <ThemeContextProvider value={theme}>
    {children}
  </ThemeContextProvider>;
);
```

and then use it in the app component

```
import React from 'react';
import YourContextProvider from './config/context';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <YourContextProvider>
      ...
    </YourContextProvider>
  );
}
```

You can still name the `YourContextProvider` as `ThemeContextProvider` if you want but I'd recommend not. It may be hard to follow for the future maintenance.

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but it doesn't work. When I import `YourContextProvider ` and use as you mentioned with `<YourContextProvider>`, React complains that `value` is required, and the default values are not accessible.

Comment: It cannot complain about the value on YourContextProvider because that component has no prop like this. Try to remove ThemeContextProvider from the YourContextProvider to render the children only, then when it works, add the ThemeContextProvider again with value inside.